# How to make socket.io only connect once

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, socket.io

When I go to another screen or update the page, a new connection is issued on socket.io. I would like that when the user enters the first page connect only once and continue with the same connection on other screens

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home.html');
});

app.get('/chat', (req, res) => {
    res.render('salachat.html');
});

app.get('/novoproduto', (req, res) => {
    res.render('novoproduto.html');
});

let messages = [];

let produtos = [];

io.on('connection', socket =>{
    console.log(`novo usuario conectado : ${socket.id}`);
    socket.emit('previousMessages', messages );
    socket.emit('previousprodutos', produtos );


    socket.on('sendMessage', data => {
        messages.push(data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('receivedMessage', data);
    });

    socket.on('sendProduto', data => {
        produtos.push(data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('receivedProdutos', data);
    });

});

server.listen(3000);
```

When I enter the route "/" creates a new connection, when I enter "/chat" or "/novoproduto" creates another

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the browser works, when it leaves a web page and load a new page, ALL resources from the original web page are disposed of. This includes webSocket or socket.io connections.  So you can't keep a socket.io connection open from page A when you replace page A with a different web page in the browser tab/window.  There is no way to do that.

The usual work-around is to just establish a new socket.io connection in the new web page and to have the server use some sort of state (often a cookie) to know which user it is so it can just rehook up whatever it needs to do for that user as if the same socket.io connection was continuing.

Other work-arounds are to use frames, where one frame is not replaced in the browser so it can hold a continuous socket.io connection or to use a single page app architecture where the browser page is not replaced as the user navigates around.